# automatic resize of image that was set as background to any mobile device

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

on wordpress, working on client responsive mobile only theme.
what i did was set an image as a background with background: URL('') with simple CSS
the problem is, i tried every possible option from cover,100% to contain and to set size of the container to setting max-height by px and what no.
the image gets either stritched and out of the container as if it was zoomed on a certain spot in the image or to the image showing on top part of the screen as in a small scale.

what i am trying to get is, when a user go on the website it will calculate the screen size and the image will fit to the screen size both width and heigh and then scroll down as the use scroll down so we wont have to stretch it more then needed.

here is what i got so far (i know a lot of it is unnecessary i was throwing everything i could at it.also seems like the @media does not always takes effect.

```css
.entry-content {
  background-image: url('http://drsofa6.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dsofatruck.jpeg');
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 300px) {
  .entry-content {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('http://drsofa6.local/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dsofatruck.jpeg');
    background-size: 5px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    background-clip: content-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="clearfix">
  <div class="wrapper-outer">

    <!-- BEGIN FEATURED IMAGE -->
    <div class="featured-image">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END FEATURED IMAGE -->

    <!-- BEGIN CUSTOM FIELD FOR EMBEDDABLE CONTENT -->
    <?php $featuredembed = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'FeaturedEmbed', true); ?>
    <div class="video-container">
      <?php echo $featuredembed; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END CUSTOM FIELD FOR EMBEDDABLE CONTENT -->

    <!-- BEGIN SHORTCODE OUTSIDE THE LOOP -->
    <div class="post-shortcode">
      <?php $shortcode = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Shortcode', true); ?>
      <?php echo do_shortcode($shortcode); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END SHORTCODE OUTSIDE THE LOOP -->

    <div class="page-wrapper">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
      <h1 class="entry-title">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->

      <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
      <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->

      <!-- BEGIN POST NAVIGATION -->
      <div class="link-pages">
        <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'bonfire').'</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
      </div>
      <!-- END POST NAVIGATION -->

      <!-- BEGIN EDIT POST LINK -->
      <?php edit_post_link(__('EDIT', 'bonfire')); ?>
      <!-- END EDIT POST LINK -->

      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.page-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.wrapper-outer -->
</div>
<!-- /#content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You said "here is what I got so far" but I don't see any code ^^

Comment: Just noticed.. edited now with the code

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML too?

Comment: Just did. i was wondering also if it will be better if i add the image to the HTML and then use CSS rather then only CSS

Comment: I apologize, but CodeSnippet doesn't render php. Do you have another source, or maybe a picture to show the problem?